# How to convert void to implicitly local variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here I'm writing logic in class file and implementing in a controller. When I'm trying to implement the code in the controller it's throwing an error as "cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable"

```
public void Getass()
        {
            var xx = from n in db.Accessors
                     join cn in db.Countrys on n.CountryID equals cn.CountryID
                     select new
                     {
                n.Name,n.Id,n.CountryID,
                                    cn.CountryName};
        }
```

Dummy.cs

```
 public JsonResult tt()
        {
             var  sss=  objrepo.Getass();

            return new JsonResult { JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
```

Comment: `void` means the method *doesn't return anything*.  Did you mean to return something from that method?

Comment: yes here i want to join two table And i Wrote this Join Logic in Class File & implementing in Controller(MVC)

Comment: `Getass` should return the collection but it is an anonymous type. Either create it in the method making the call or create a class to hold the result

Comment: But what should the (poorly named) `Getass` method *return*?  I assume you want it to return `xx`, but what type is that variable?  Note also that the `tt` method doesn't return the `sss` data either.

Comment: could u plz mention any supported code here im a Learner

Comment: Note that in English, you don't need to capitalize most words, except for the first word in a sentence, the letter I when referring to yourself, and some proper nouns.

Comment: StackOverflow is not meant to be a guided learning site.  It is a site for _specific_ problems.  Read tutorials, books, documentation, etc. to learn and come back with specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getass should return the collection but it is an anonymous type. Either create it in the method making the call

```
public JsonResult tt()
{
     var xx = from n in db.Accessors
              join cn in db.Countrys on n.CountryID equals cn.CountryID
              select new
              {
                 n.Name,
                 n.Id,
                 n.CountryID,
                 cn.CountryName
              };

    return Json(xx, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

or create a class to hold the result

```
public class MyModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CountryID { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}

public IList<MyModel> GetAccessors()
{
    var xx = from n in db.Accessors
             join cn in db.Countrys on n.CountryID equals cn.CountryID
             select new MyModel 
             {
                 Name = n.Name,
                 Id = n.Id,
                 CountryID = n.CountryID,
                 CountryName = cn.CountryName
             };
    return xx.ToList();
}

public JsonResult tt()
{
     var  sss=  objrepo.GetAccessors();

    return Json(sss, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thank u Soo much Mr.NKoSi

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a concrete type to return that from your method.  `void` means the method doesn't return *anything*, and you can't use `var` as a return type.

So your choices are:

- Create a concrete type and have your query create objects of that type (and change your return type to `IEnumerable<{type}>` or similar
- Put the query from `Getass` inside the `tt` method so you *can* use an anonymous type.

Answer (score 0):

you can't return a void type and expecting a result that you can assign to a variable

more you are creating an anonymous type by doing this

```
  select new  {
                n.Name,n.Id,n.CountryID,
                                    cn.CountryName};
```

if you want to return it oops, 
you can't return an anonymous type because you haven't the name at compilation time. c# will assign an arbitrary name once compiled so you have to use object type

You can only return object, or container of objects, e.g. `IEnumerable<object>, IList<object>,` etc.